# awk/gsub - display string before, then after, then before gsub

Tags: svn, awk, gsub

FYI, I'm an awk/gsub noob.

I have a svn dump i'm trying to create a users.txt from, format...

```
user.name = user name <user.name@foo.com>
```

Here's where I have got to...

```
awk '/svn:author/ { getline; getline; gsub("[\.]", " ", $1); print $0, " = ", $1 , " <", $0, "@foo.com>"}' svn_dmp | sort | uniq
```

Unfortunately, it is changing the value of `$0` and removing all `.` so I get...

```
mr foo = mr foo <mr foo@foo.com>
```

I was hoping that the `gsub` would write the new string to `$1` and preserve `$0`. How do I swap the dot for a space in only the middle `mr.foo`?

Comment: `$0` is the whole line, which includes `$1`, so when you change `$1` you're changing that portion of `$0` as well.

Comment: Make sure to read and fully understand all the caveats and gothcas about getline at http://awk.info/?tip/getline before using it and then, usually, you won't. Your problem does not require getline and the way you are using it is wrong anyway. Post a few lines of sample input and expected output and we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$0` is the whole line, which includes `$1`, so when you change `$1` you're changing that portion of `$0` as well. If you want to preserve the original `$0` you need to save it in another variable before modifying `$1`.

Something like

```
$ echo 'mr.foo' | awk '{orig=$0
                        gsub("[\.]", " ", $1)
                        print orig " = "  $1 " <" orig "@foo.com>"}'

mr.foo = mr foo <mr.foo@foo.com>
```